# How to call multiple actions (from hwrp - library) actions in 1 ruby_block

Tags: chef-infra

I've modified the community database cookbook in order to query the oracle client from multiple chef cookbooks. I'm new to Chef and Ruby and I'm having problems trying to call the actions from the library dir in which I have the resource & provider ruby files. (I know the queries themselves work as I've tried them with straight ruby_blocks before creating library files.)

For all the cookbooks/recipes I will be creating, I need to query the database multiple times for logging & pulling information to/from the db. I have a 'query', 'db', & 'close' action set up. I want the 'db' action to connect to the db and remain open throughout the recipes, while I perform queries on the db with the 'query' action (a case statement identifies which query to perform) and finally 'close' the connection when all processing is complete in the recipe.

I've looked around to see if I can do this with a library/hwrp and tried several possibilities but have been unsuccessful. I don't think I can use Chef's Notifications for this because the db has to remain connected throughout the recipe and then closed as the last step or upon error? Can I actually do this or should I create a stand alone library/helper.rb module, as I've seen suggested, instead of modifying the existing community database library cookbook?

Below, is a rough example of what I am trying to do as pseudo code in just one ruby_block. Thanks in advance for your patience and any advisement in this regard.

```
ruby_block "myBlock" do
  block do
    establishDBConnection_action_db
    writelogRecordToDBBeginningStep_action_query_when1
    performChefPlatformResource
    getFlagFromDBOkToProceed_action_query_when2
    closeDBConnection_action_close 
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a DB as a lock down mechanism ? Sounds like a library would be a better fit in this case as you're not changing a state but willing to make a complex change with read and write to DB around the state change itself.

Comment: I'd use a library.  Actions on resources are meant to denote desired state, not to act as part of a processing flow.

Comment: I'm required to use db for logging, processing and node syncing. I will look to transitioning to a helper library then - thank you all for your feedback.